# Using Node package in NativeScript app

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I am learning NativeScript. For example, I would like to include this [Guid generator package](https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid) in my NativeScript app. My question is, how? I look at the directory structure generated by the command-line tool and I see the following relevant pieces:

```
node_modules
app
  tns_modules
  package.json
package.json
```

Do I add `node-uuid` to the ./package.json or the ./app/package.json? How do I reference it in my app then? For example, if I want to use uuid from the app.js file, what does that look like? I'm a little confused because of the package structure of NativeScript and how things actually get loaded at runtime.

Thanks

Comment: You can see this blog post: https://www.nativescript.org/blog/using-npm-modules-and-nativescript-plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run npm install from the root of your {N} app.

```
npm install --save node-uuid
```

The dependency will be added to the outer package.json.

And then in your app.js file, just use it like usual.

```
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
```

When you run `tns run <platform>` or `tns build <platform>`, the modules inside `node_modules/` will be copied to folder under `platforms/`, take Android for example, it will be at `platforms/android/assets/app/tns_modules/node-uuid`. The building process is completed under `platforms/` directory.